# Thunderbird: Set default sender alias to receiver address

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have catch-all configured on my email server so I can give a new email address to every service that I use.

When I reply to an email in Thunderbird it would be great if the default `From:` field would contain the address under which I received the email. I know that I can customize the Sender address manually, but it's a hassle to do it every time.

Is there a config flag, or an Add-On that can do that? Maybe a hint where Thunderbird's relevant code is? Maybe I can do it myself :)

Example:

Received email:
[image]

I hit the reply button
[image]

But I want the `From:` (here: "Von", sorry for the German) field to already have the address which received the email in the first place.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found https://github.com/absorb-it/Virtual-Identity, which does exactly what I want.